# Prove that spec$(f(A)) = f$(spec$(A)).$

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

Can someone please explain this proof to me? Thanks!

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and let $f(x)$ be a polynomial. Prove that spec$(f(A)) = f$(spec$(A))$ (where if $S \subseteq \mathbb{C},$ $f(S) :=$ $\{ f(s) : s \in S\}$).

Comment: See any book on the subject of functional analysis.  Also, you may try Applied Analysis by Hunter and Nachtergaele.  This is called the Spectral Mapping Theorem.  Its Googleable.

Comment: https://math.uc.edu/~halpern/Linear.algebra/ho/Spectral.mapping.thm.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The sophisticated machinery that is Google has this one for us.  For a more general answer see the first generated answer, for your specific question see the second generated answer.

http://bit.ly/1oKYXMW